# Allow limited access to secured resources via spring web security

Tags: spring-security

Some advice needed

I use spring web security e.g.

```
 @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers().frameOptions().disable()
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/app/profile-info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll();

}
```

To access the API 'app' you have to be authenticated. However I want to allow anyone to use the app api for a period of time e.g. they can use the api 3 times per day after which they need to sign up for the service

I have looked into several solutions e.g. using ip and storing the amount of times they have used the API

I was wondering is there a mechanism in spring security to achieve the above? I have been unable to find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are describing is not an *authentication* problem, but ***authorization***.

The way I see it is that user should be identified and authenticated (e.g. registered or identified via IP/SMS/etc. if service can be used without registration). Then you'll associate given quota with a user (a simple field in DB) and will check it before executing any method in your API. As far as I know, it can be achieved with spring security via [Attribute-Based Access Control](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-attribute-based-access-control-with-spring) where your custom attribute will check if a user is out of quota.

Also, pay attention to a problem called [Race condition](https://www.sans.edu/cyber-research/security-laboratory/article/race-cndtns): a user can try to access resources faster (by creating a lot of simultaneous requests) than a quota counter could be updated in DB. Seen it in a couple spring applications that I've been working with.